# apache Thrift TNonblockingServer Error

Tags: c++, thrift

I've been following [Thrift C++ wiki tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++). and everything works fine with TSimpleServer. 
But, when I try to implement TNonblockingServer I'm getting this error :(

```
undefined reference to `apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::serve()
undefined reference to `apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::~TNonblockingServer()
```

I think its something related to the header files or the namespaces.
The following headers im using:

```
#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <thrift/concurrency/ThreadManager.h>
#include <thrift/concurrency/PosixThreadFactory.h>
#include <thrift/server/TThreadedServer.h>
#include <thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.h>

using namespace ::apache::thrift;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::concurrency;
```

any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is really late reply.
It is due to missing libthriftnb library for TNonblockingServer.

while Tsimplesever and TThreadedServer are in libthrift library so it was works with you.